# Twitter login with React and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, twitter

I tried to implement Twitter login with react and laravel.

scenario 1
[image]

scenario 2

[image]

scenario 3
[image]

Not all of them work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The problem you're facing has been implemented countless times throughout developers, the real issue is the question itself. Just saying "Nothing works" doesn't help anyone, or give them a picture of what's happening.
Tell us what you have tried, which approach fails WHERE exactly, code snippets, general ideas etc. 
I am sure that lots of people would help if the answer is more than diagrams

Comment: Which of the three scenarios do not work? What error are you receiving? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)